# Standard form in C

Tags: c

After a few hours of searching I have not been able to find an answer, but if this is a duplicate please point me in the correct direction.

Will a C program accept a standard form input into something like `scanf("%f",&float);` from the keyboard. Standard form is writing a number like 2400 as 2.4E3 if this helps you understand what I am asking.

I must stress this MUST be from the keyboard.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? That would have taken less time than searching, posting this question, and waiting for an answer...

Comment: Because it does not tell me if it is platform independent, hence the question.

Comment: Do you want to accept `2.4E3` and reject `2400`? That's not at all clear from your question, and it should be. BTW, `2.4E3` is called "scientific notation", not "standard form".

Comment: C does not have a concept of "keyboard" or terminals. Only Streams. And RTF(ine)M !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

1. `scanf` works identically, regardless of whether `stdin` is connected to a terminal, a file, or some other input stream.
2. The `%a`, `%e`, `%f`, `%g` scanf format codes all do the same thing: interpret the longest string which would be acceptable to `strtod` (§7.21.6.2/12). (And so do `%A`, `%E`, `%F` and `%G` -- paragraph 14 of the same clause.) The redundancy is because `scanf` formats accepts the same format codes as `printf`.

`strtod` accepts any of the following (§7.22.1.3/3):

> - a nonempty sequence of decimal digits optionally containing a decimal-point character, then an optional exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
> - a 0x or 0X, then a nonempty sequence of hexadecimal digits optionally containing a decimal-point character, then an optional binary exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
> - INF or INFINITY, ignoring case
> - NAN or NAN(n-char-sequenceopt), ignoring case in the NAN part,…

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is being accepted from my terminal and also the [IDEone](http://ideone.com/4v3mnA) interpreter (added it in stdin which is the same as "from the keyboard").

And probably a typo, but you have missed the `""` in

```
scanf("%f", &float)
```

Comment: And `float` is a keyword, the name of the type. You need the name of a variable of type `float`.

Comment: Yes, it is changed in my code, but good that you pointed it out for OP.